# Unitary operator if and only if statement

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be the inner product space of complex-valued continuous functions on [0,1] with the inner product $<f,g>=\int_0^1 f(t) \bar{g(t)} dt$. Let $h \in V$, and define $T:V \rightarrow V$ by $T(f)=hf$. Prove that T is a unitary operator if and only if $|h(t)|=1$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

$\rightarrow$:If T is a unitary operator, then for any $f \in V$, $||T(f)||=||f||$ by definition. 
From the problem, we have $||T(f)||^2=||hf||^2$. I feel like I am not sure how to continue with this. Any help is appreciated (just the front side)

Comment: Use the fact an operator is unitary if and only if its eigenvalues lie on the unit circle.

Comment: I have added some details to my answer. If you need more details please tell me where exactly you have difficulty. I will be happy to help.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yeah that's enough, I have difficulty in representing f,g in inner product spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Verify from definition of adoint that $T^{*}f=f\overline {h}$. Hence $TT^{*}f=T^{*}T f=f|h|^{2}$. $T$ is unitary iff $TT^{*}=T^{*}T=I$ iff $|h|^{2}=1$.

Proof of the fact that $T^{*}f=f\overline {h}$: $T^{*}f$ is defined by the equation $\int_0^{1} (T^{*}f) \overline g =\int_0^{1} f \overline {Tg}$ for all $g \in V$ which can be written as  $\int_0^{1} (T^{*}f) \overline g =\int_0^{1} f \overline {g}\overline {h}$ for all $g \in V$ or $\int_0^{1} (T^{*}f-f \overline {h}) \overline g =0$ . Put $g=T^{*}f-f\overline {h}$ to get $\int_0^{1} |T^{*}f-f\overline {h}|^{2}=0$. This implies that $T^{*}f-f\overline {h}=0$ or $T^{*}f=f\overline {h}$. [I have used the following fact: if $\phi$ is a non-negative continuous function such that $\int_0^{1} \phi (x)dx=0$ then $\phi (x)=0$ for all $x$].